# “User-defined type not defined” error, no lines highlighted - what's the error?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly new to VBA. I'm trying to write a function that will return the number of columns that contain a value.

So for instance, if "37" is present 2x in column A, 3x in column B, and 0x in ColumnC, the function will return 2.

When I run this, it gives me an error - "user-defined type not defined." VBA doesn't indicate a particular line that has the issue.

```
Function countUniqueCols(toFind As Text, CASarray As Object) As Integer
    Dim numCols As Integer
    numCols = 0
    Dim currentCol As Column
    For Each currentCol In CASarray.Columns
        For Each currentRow In currentCol.Rows
            If InStr(1, Cells(currentRow, currentCol).value, toFind) Then
                numCols = numCols + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next currentRow
    Next currentCol
    countUniqueCols = numCols
End Function
```

Thoughts? Thanks so much!

Comment: You may need to declare `CASarray` as a Range.

Comment: I tried that earlier - wasn't working. That's why I went generic, to Object. As far as my understanding goes, that shouldn't throw anything off though?

Answer (score 2):

Doh!!!  I was scratching my head for a while on this, even resorting to attempting to step through the code - and then I suddenly spotted it - **Text**:

```
Function countUniqueCols(toFind As Text, CASarray As Object) As Integer
```

should be:

```
Function countUniqueCols(toFind As String, CASarray As Range) As Integer
```

`Text` is not a valid VBA data type.

And then, just when I thought that I had the problem solved, I tried running it again, and found `Column`, which will need to be `Range`, i.e.

```
Dim currentCol As Column
```

should be

```
Dim currentCol As Range
```

And then I found that `currentRow` wasn't defined.  And that the `Cells(currentRow, currentCol)` was wrong.

The following code should work:

```
Function countUniqueCols(toFind As String, CASarray As Range) As Integer
    Dim numCols As Integer
    numCols = 0
    Dim currentCol As Range
    Dim currentRow As Range
    For Each currentCol In CASarray.Columns
        For Each currentRow In currentCol.Rows
            If InStr(1, currentRow.Value, toFind) Then
                numCols = numCols + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next currentRow
    Next currentCol
    countUniqueCols = numCols
End Function
```

But Shai's code would be better, so I am only leaving this here so that you can see the subtle errors that existed in the existing code.

Comment: @ShaiRado - My code was just fixing the specific problems with the original code - your code gives the better way to achieve the underlying goal, so hopefully the OP will accept it.  (P.S.  Another way of testing the code is `=countUniqueCols("Ian",Sheet1!A1:D1000)` - it's a valid UDF, and I suspect that's how the OP is using it.)

Comment: Your explanations about the errors are better, I was just giving you credit and upvoted (on my side)

Answer (score 1):

Since it doesn't matter (according to your post) how many times `toFind` is found within a column (as long as it's >= 1), then you can loop through the `CASarray` range's columns, and for each column use the `Application.Match` to find a single match.

In this case, if `If Not IsError(Application.Match(toFind, currentCol, 0)) Then` means a match was found within this column, so add a count of 1 to `numCols`.

The second `Sub` I've added is to make sure you use the right parameters (and fully qualified) when you call this function.

***Function countUniqueCols* Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function countUniqueCols(toFind As String, CASarray As Range) As Long

    Dim numCols As Long, currentCol As Range

    numCols = 0

    For Each currentCol In CASarray.Columns
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(toFind, currentCol, 0)) Then
            numCols = numCols + 1
        End If
    Next currentCol
    countUniqueCols = numCols

End Function
```

***Sub Test_countUniqueCols* Code** (to test the Function)

```
Sub Test_countUniqueCols()

Dim Res As Long

Res = countUniqueCols("Shai", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D1000"))    
MsgBox Res

End Sub
```

Comment: @Aanandh Chandrasekar have you tested my code above ? is it working ? if it does the mark as "ANSWSER" , click on the check mark next to my answer (it will turn green)